# Cannot access network connected to OpenVPN server

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

The VPN server (Linux) is behind a router. I want to connect from an external network to my VPN server and access devices in the server’s local network (and the server itself).

The local network’s address range is 192.168.178.0/24

I forwarded some ports to my VPN server, too: 1194, 80, 21, 443, 1723

!!I deleted previous information because body limit was reached!!

EDIT 4: Complete list of current settings:
This is my server config:

---

```
port 1194  
proto udp  
dev tap  
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt  
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/VPNServer.crt  
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/VPNServer.key  
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh1024.pem  
server-bridge 192.168.178.1 255.255.255.0 192.168.178.111 192.168.178.120
push "route-gateway 192.168.178.0 255.255.255.0" 
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp" 
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.178.1"
client-to-client  
duplicate-cn  
keepalive 10 120  
comp-lzo  
persist-key  
persist-tun  
status openvpn-status.log  
log         openvpn.log  
log-append  openvpn.log  
verb 3
```

---

My client config looks like this.

---

```
port 1194
client  
dev tap  
proto udp  
remote mydyndns
resolv-retry infinite  
nobind  
persist-key  
persist-tun  
ca ca.crt  
cert client.crt    
key client.key
ns-cert-type server  
comp-lzo  
verb 3
```

---

My interface configuration for the server looks like this:

---

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
address 192.168.178.123
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.178.1
bridge_ports eth0
dns-nameservers 192.168.178.1

iface eth0 inet manual
up ifconfig $IFACE 0.0.0.0 up
up ip link set $IFACE promisc on
down ip link set $IFACE promisc off
down ifconfig $IFACE down
```

---

And my rc.local

---

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

And my sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward output is net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

My client log output is as followed:

```
Fri Sep 12 13:03:58 2014 OpenVPN 2.3.4 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [IPv6] built on Aug  7 2014
Fri Sep 12 13:03:58 2014 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014, LZO 2.05
Enter Management Password:
Fri Sep 12 13:03:58 2014 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Fri Sep 12 13:03:58 2014 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Fri Sep 12 13:03:59 2014 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Fri Sep 12 13:03:59 2014 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Fri Sep 12 13:03:59 2014 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Fri Sep 12 13:03:59 2014 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Fri Sep 12 13:03:59 2014 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Fri Sep 12 13:03:59 2014 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
Fri Sep 12 13:03:59 2014 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1410519839,RESOLVE,,,
Fri Sep 12 13:04:00 2014 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Fri Sep 12 13:04:00 2014 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]86.103.178.165:1194
Fri Sep 12 13:04:00 2014 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1410519840,WAIT,,,
Fri Sep 12 13:04:00 2014 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1410519840,AUTH,,,
Fri Sep 12 13:04:00 2014 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]86.103.178.165:1194, sid=bebc894c 68e04336
Fri Sep 12 13:04:02 2014 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=DE, ST=SH, L=Kiel, OU=changeme, CN=j0chn.spdns.de, name=changeme, emailAddress=matthias_j_fischer@hotmail.de
Fri Sep 12 13:04:02 2014 VERIFY OK: nsCertType=SERVER
Fri Sep 12 13:04:02 2014 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=DE, ST=SH, L=Kiel, OU=changeme, CN=j0chn.spdns.de, name=changeme, emailAddress=matthias_j_fischer@hotmail.de
Fri Sep 12 13:04:05 2014 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Fri Sep 12 13:04:05 2014 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Sep 12 13:04:05 2014 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Fri Sep 12 13:04:05 2014 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Sep 12 13:04:05 2014 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 1024 bit RSA
Fri Sep 12 13:04:05 2014 [j0chn.spdns.de] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]86.103.178.165:1194
Fri Sep 12 13:04:06 2014 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1410519846,GET_CONFIG,,,
Fri Sep 12 13:04:08 2014 SENT CONTROL [j0chn.spdns.de]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Fri Sep 12 13:04:08 2014 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,route-gateway 192.168.178.1,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222,dhcp-option DNS 192.168.178.1,route-gateway 192.168.178.1,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 192.168.178.112 255.255.255.0'
Fri Sep 12 13:04:08 2014 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Fri Sep 12 13:04:08 2014 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Fri Sep 12 13:04:08 2014 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Fri Sep 12 13:04:08 2014 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
Fri Sep 12 13:04:08 2014 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Fri Sep 12 13:04:08 2014 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Fri Sep 12 13:04:08 2014 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1410519848,ASSIGN_IP,,192.168.178.112,
Fri Sep 12 13:04:08 2014 open_tun, tt->ipv6=0
Fri Sep 12 13:04:08 2014 TAP-WIN32 device [Ethernet 2] opened: \\.\Global\{4DD19686-B673-493E-99DB-23F3D1AF7239}.tap
Fri Sep 12 13:04:08 2014 TAP-Windows Driver Version 9.21 
Fri Sep 12 13:04:08 2014 Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 192.168.178.112/255.255.255.0 on interface {4DD19686-B673-493E-99DB-23F3D1AF7239} [DHCP-serv: 192.168.178.0, lease-time: 31536000]
Fri Sep 12 13:04:08 2014 Successful ARP Flush on interface [25] {4DD19686-B673-493E-99DB-23F3D1AF7239}
Fri Sep 12 13:04:13 2014 TEST ROUTES: 1/1 succeeded len=0 ret=1 a=0 u/d=up
Fri Sep 12 13:04:13 2014 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 86.103.178.165 MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.42.129
Fri Sep 12 13:04:13 2014 ROUTE: CreateIpForwardEntry succeeded with dwForwardMetric1=10 and dwForwardType=4
Fri Sep 12 13:04:13 2014 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
Fri Sep 12 13:04:13 2014 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 192.168.42.129 MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.42.129 IF 24
Fri Sep 12 13:04:13 2014 ROUTE: CreateIpForwardEntry succeeded with dwForwardMetric1=10 and dwForwardType=4
Fri Sep 12 13:04:13 2014 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
Fri Sep 12 13:04:13 2014 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 0.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 192.168.178.1
Fri Sep 12 13:04:13 2014 ROUTE: CreateIpForwardEntry succeeded with dwForwardMetric1=20 and     dwForwardType=4
Fri Sep 12 13:04:13 2014 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
Fri Sep 12 13:04:13 2014 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 128.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 192.168.178.1
Fri Sep 12 13:04:13 2014 ROUTE: CreateIpForwardEntry succeeded with dwForwardMetric1=20 and dwForwardType=4
Fri Sep 12 13:04:13 2014 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
Fri Sep 12 13:04:13 2014 Initialization Sequence Completed
Fri Sep 12 13:04:13 2014 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1410519853,CONNECTED,SUCCESS,192.168.178.112,86.103.178.165
```

---

Edit 5:
The new server log.

```
Fri Sep 12 17:15:07 2014 MULTI: multi_create_instance called
Fri Sep 12 17:15:07 2014 109.47.193.65:62284 Re-using SSL/TLS context
Fri Sep 12 17:15:07 2014 109.47.193.65:62284 LZO compression initialized
Fri Sep 12 17:15:07 2014 109.47.193.65:62284 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1574 D:138 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Fri Sep 12 17:15:07 2014 109.47.193.65:62284 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1574 D:1450 EF:42 EB:135 ET:32 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Fri Sep 12 17:15:07 2014 109.47.193.65:62284 Local Options hash (VER=V4): 'f7df56b8'
Fri Sep 12 17:15:07 2014 109.47.193.65:62284 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): 'd79ca330'
Fri Sep 12 17:15:07 2014 109.47.193.65:62284 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]109.47.193.65:62284, sid=c07bdc21 48d01394
Fri Sep 12 17:15:08 2014 109.47.193.65:62284 VERIFY OK: depth=1, /C=DE/ST=SH/L=Kiel/OU=changeme/CN=j0chn.spdns.de/name=changeme/ema$
Fri Sep 12 17:15:08 2014 109.47.193.65:62284 VERIFY OK: depth=0, /C=DE/ST=SH/L=Kiel/OU=changeme/CN=j0chns/name=changeme/emailAddres$
Fri Sep 12 17:15:09 2014 109.47.193.65:62284 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Fri Sep 12 17:15:09 2014 109.47.193.65:62284 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Sep 12 17:15:09 2014 109.47.193.65:62284 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Fri Sep 12 17:15:09 2014 109.47.193.65:62284 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Sep 12 17:15:09 2014 109.47.193.65:62284 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 1024 bit RSA
Fri Sep 12 17:15:09 2014 109.47.193.65:62284 [j0chns] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]109.47.193.65:62284
Fri Sep 12 17:15:09 2014 j0chns/109.47.193.65:62284 MULTI_sva: pool returned IPv4=192.168.178.111, IPv6=bccd:800:8ced:200:14c2:700:$
Fri Sep 12 17:15:11 2014 j0chns/109.47.193.65:62284 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST'
Fri Sep 12 17:15:11 2014 j0chns/109.47.193.65:62284 send_push_reply(): safe_cap=960
Fri Sep 12 17:15:11 2014 j0chns/109.47.193.65:62284 SENT CONTROL [j0chns]: 'PUSH_REPLY,route-gateway 192.168.178.1,redirect-gateway$
Fri Sep 12 17:15:11 2014 j0chns/109.47.193.65:62284 MULTI: Learn: 00:ff:4d:d1:96:86 -> j0chns/109.47.193.65:62284
Fri Sep 12 17:18:14 2014 MULTI: multi_create_instance called
Fri Sep 12 17:18:14 2014 86.103.178.165:57350 Re-using SSL/TLS context
Fri Sep 12 17:18:14 2014 86.103.178.165:57350 LZO compression initialized
Fri Sep 12 17:18:14 2014 86.103.178.165:57350 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1574 D:138 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Fri Sep 12 17:18:14 2014 86.103.178.165:57350 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1574 D:1450 EF:42 EB:135 ET:32 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Fri Sep 12 17:18:14 2014 86.103.178.165:57350 Local Options hash (VER=V4): 'f7df56b8'
Fri Sep 12 17:18:14 2014 86.103.178.165:57350 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): 'd79ca330'
Fri Sep 12 17:18:14 2014 86.103.178.165:57350 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]86.103.178.165:57350, sid=25abeaaa 58473451
Fri Sep 12 17:18:14 2014 86.103.178.165:57350 VERIFY OK: depth=1, /C=DE/ST=SH/L=Kiel/OU=changeme/CN=j0chn.spdns.de/name=changeme/em$
Fri Sep 12 17:18:14 2014 86.103.178.165:57350 VERIFY OK: depth=0, /C=DE/ST=SH/L=Kiel/OU=changeme/CN=j0chns/name=changeme/emailAddre$
Fri Sep 12 17:18:14 2014 86.103.178.165:57350 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Fri Sep 12 17:18:14 2014 86.103.178.165:57350 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Sep 12 17:18:14 2014 86.103.178.165:57350 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Fri Sep 12 17:18:14 2014 86.103.178.165:57350 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Sep 12 17:18:14 2014 86.103.178.165:57350 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 1024 bit RSA
Fri Sep 12 17:18:14 2014 86.103.178.165:57350 [j0chns] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]86.103.178.165:57350
Fri Sep 12 17:18:14 2014 j0chns/86.103.178.165:57350 MULTI_sva: pool returned IPv4=192.168.178.112, IPv6=bccd:800:8ced:200:14c2:700$
Fri Sep 12 17:18:17 2014 j0chns/86.103.178.165:57350 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST'
Fri Sep 12 17:18:17 2014 j0chns/86.103.178.165:57350 send_push_reply(): safe_cap=960
Fri Sep 12 17:18:17 2014 j0chns/86.103.178.165:57350 SENT CONTROL [j0chns]: 'PUSH_REPLY,route-gateway 192.168.178.1,redirect-gatewa$
Fri Sep 12 17:18:18 2014 j0chns/86.103.178.165:57350 MULTI: Learn: 00:ff:4d:d1:96:86 -> j0chns/86.103.178.165:57350
```

---

And another edit:
I increased the verbose level from 3 to 9 and got new information:

```
Sat Sep 13 17:36:11 2014 us=76111 TLS State Error: No TLS state for client  [AF_INET]86.103.202.242:55140, opcode=6
Sat Sep 13 17:36:11 2014 us=76308 GET INST BY REAL: 86.103.202.242:55140 [failed]
```

Maybe this can help!?

Comment: I rewrote your post, please check if all the facts are accurate. Please also add the following information: Output of `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`; which Linux distribution you’re using

Comment: Oh yeah, and static route you added to your router is pointless because IPTables is configured to reject these packets. ;) I just noticed I forgot to ask about the now second-to-last paragraph: Can you please describe in greater detail how the client behaves? Can it still access the internet? Can it ping 192.168.178.123 when VPN-connected? Does the VPN log contain a success message about adding the route?

Comment: In 2nd edit I post my log after setting up openvpn with MariusMatutiaes suggestion.

Comment: Well, you made some progress: the last line of your log says: **MANAGEMENT:   >STATE:1410365314,CONNECTED,SUCCESS,192.168.178.111,86.103.189.21**, so the client thinks everything is fine. Have you modified the iptables rules on the server, to reflect the change of subnet, from 10.8.0.0 to 192.168.178.111?

Comment: Please see my EDIT

Comment: Now I can connect again and get an IP in range (192.168.178.111). But I still can't ping any other network clients. I posted my new client log in 3rd edit. Maybe you can tell me where to find server log when openvpn.log and openvpn-status.log are emtpy?!

Comment: Try substituting *dev tap* with *dev tap0* in the server config file. Reboot pc, try connecting again. N, there are no other settings to be changed, on the client side. Besides, you are connected just fine.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I can't ping any other local network Ressources ( server ir router)

Answer (score 0):

Your client file is missing both the IP address of the remote server, and the indication of the port on which to contact the server itself. In other words, you are missing:

```
 port 1194
 remote IP.ADDRESS.OF.SERVER
```

Also, I do not understand why you are using the subnet 10.8.0.0/24 for your clients. You have already chosen a *tap* interface for a bridged OpenVPN (good choice, makes access to all pcs on the LAN much easier at no extra cost), so there is no reason to use a distinct subnet. Your server file should contain the statements

```
 server-bridge 192.168.178.1 255.255.255.0 192.168.178.111 192.168.178.120
 push "route-gateway 192.168.178.1"
 push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
 push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.178.1"
 push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
```

The first statement instructs the server to draw IP addresses for remote clients in the pool 192.168.178.(111-120). Just make sure the DHCP server on your LAN is not trying to use these addresses itself, in which case you will have to choose a different pool for the OpenVPN pool. The other statements are obvious.

Lastly, there should be no need to define separate routes, apart from the above statements.

EDIT:

you need to change iptables and make a bridge on the server.

1. Change your /etc/netorking/interfaces file to look like this:

   auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

   auto br0 
    iface br0 inet static
       address 192.168.178.123
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       gateway 192.168.178.1
       bridge_ports eth0
       dns-nameservers 192.168.178.1

   iface eth0 inet manual
       up ifconfig $IFACE 0.0.0.0 up
       up ip link set $IFACE promisc on
       down ip link set $IFACE promisc off
       down ifconfig $IFACE down

Reboot the server for this to take effect. Check that the server is correctly connected to the internet. Then change the iptables rules as follows:

```
 iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
 iptables -t nat –A POSTROUTING -o br0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Start the OpenVPN server, and add the tap0 interface to the bridge,

```
 sudo brctl addif br0 tap0
```

Now try connecting from the client.

EDIT 2:

This iptables rule

```
 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

should be

```
 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o br0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Also, please use **tap0** instead of *tap* in the server conf file. Reboot and let me know, pls.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it still does not work. The log is in my 2nd edit.

Comment: And where did he say he wants to redirect the internet? ;)

Comment: Is there any special setting I have to do on client side?

Comment: @j0chn Do you have other iptables rule, besides the above?

Comment: No, I don't have any other rules. But I changed my SD Card now and have to reinstall my Raspberry. I will redo all configurations told above and will tell you if it works then.

Comment: My edit 4 shows my current settings and additionally I was able to get a server log (code=113)

Comment: @j0chn Please see my new edit.

Comment: Still can't ping network ressource in lan. Edit 5 shows new server log